# Do I need to standardize if I don't care about covariate effects? (Elastic Net Regression)

Tags: regression, classification, standardization, elastic-net

I am using elastic net logistic regression to develop a classification model. I understand that generally we standardize the covariates before fitting any models so that we "penalize fairly" all the covariates, even if they have different ranges, etc.

But, hypothetically, let's say I do not care about which individual covariates are selected in this process, or how they effect the outcome on an individual level, because my number 1 goal is optimizing the performance of my model.  If this is the case, do I still need to standardize my covariates before fitting my model?  I wouldn't care if I penalize one covariate more than the other because all I am trying to do is find the model that is best for classification.

But would I be doing something wrong mathematically?  Would my model be incorrect in some other way?

Comment: Did you try it?  This is the type of question that leads naturally to experiments.

Comment: I did try it and it does perform better.  But I am wondering if I am violating some other assumptions in the model.